# Anyone know how do I delete a line that is appearing in my chart on Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, graph, charts

I am currently using a Microsoft Visual Studio.

And I created a line chart with my data. However, it's appearing im my graph a line that links the first data with the last.

Anyone could help me to delete this line please.

Solution: I understood what had happened in my code was a sentence doubled ... it was only necessary to delete.

Comment: Mmathis and Jens...take a look on my chart: https://imageshack.com/i/masow5j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. What solved it for me was recreating the data from the source and pointing my code to the new data set. The data source was a query to an MSSQL database table. I suspect the chart renderer was reading the data in an improper order and that order was incorrect in the table.  My question can be found here for others that come upon this.
(I would have done this as a comment but I don't have enough rep yet)

[Mysterious line in winforms Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378958/winform-chart-control-not-creating-proper-line-chart)

Answer (score 0):

That's what a `Line` (or `FastLine`) chart does. Change it to a `Point` (or `FastPoint`) chart if you don't want a line connecting your points.

Comment: mmathis,hi...i need to link all my points. But, I don't want a line that link my first and my last data. do you know what I mean?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Can you post a screenshot to some other image hosting site (your google drive link above isn't working for me)?

Comment: You need to order the data that you add by x-value before you add the data to the chart. Lines are drawn from one point to the next in the points list.

Comment: the program creates a polygon instead of a line chart,i'd like to delete this line that being highlighted

Comment: When you look at the list of `Points` in the series, are they all correct? Is the left-most point in there twice? Post the code you're using the create the chart and fill it in your original post.